# edb debugger: Failed to open and attach to process, please check priviledges and try again

Tags: debugging, edb

When opening a binary file, I got the "Could not open" dialog with below
error:

> Failed to open and attach to process,
>   please check priviledges and try
>   again.

*(it should be privileges instead of priviledges)*

Steps to reproduce:

- Start edb and open a binary file with
  File --> Open
- Or open it directly    from Terminal:
  edb --run    /path/to/binary/file

Build date & platform:

```
dev-util/edb [1]
     Available versions:  (~)0.9.17!m!s
     Installed versions:  0.9.17!m!s(06:48:39 PM 04/17/2011)
     Homepage:            http://www.codef00.com/projects#debugger
     Description:         EDB "Evan's Debugger" (OllyDbg workalike for Linux)
```

on Gentoo r10 - 2.6.31

Below is the info when run it with gdb:

```
(gdb) run --run virus.doc.bin 
Starting program: /usr/bin/edb --run virus.doc.bin
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Starting edb version: 0.9.17 
Please Report Bugs & Requests At: http://bugs.codef00.com/
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libAnalyzer.so                 : 0x81dff18
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libBinarySearcher.so           : 0x81f1ea8
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libBookmarks.so                : 0x81f1a00
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libBreakpointManager.so        : 0x8250fe0
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libCheckVersion.so             : 0x81eb970
[load_plugins] Loading Core Plugin: libDebuggerCore.so        : 0x824b380
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libDumpState.so                : 0x8250938
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libELFBinaryInfo.so            : 0x82499c8
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libEnvironment.so              : 0x8253fa0
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libFunctionDB.so               : 0x824c768
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libFunctionFinder.so           : 0x824a0c0
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libHardwareBreakpoints.so      : 0x8257490
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libHeapAnalyzer.so             : 0x82586b0
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libOpcodeSearcher.so           : 0x8249940
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libOpenFiles.so                : 0x82574b0
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libReferences.so               : 0x82592b0
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libROPTool.so                  : 0x8259278
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libSessionManager.so           : 0x8258c90
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libStringSearcher.so           : 0x825b3d0
[load_plugins] Loading Plugin: libSymbolViewer.so             : 0x8255308
[Function Database] loaded with 103 function definitions. 
[New Thread 0xb26e0b70 (LWP 2401)]
[New Thread 0xb1d0eb70 (LWP 2481)]
comparing versions: [2321] [2321]
[Thread 0xb1d0eb70 (LWP 2481) exited]
[Thread 0xb26e0b70 (LWP 2401) exited]

Program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

PS: I also tried to run it as root but still got the same error.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of edb. So first of all, thanks for your interest in my debugger :-).

If anyone is interested in the follow up, quanta contacted me through my bugzilla, so you can see more of the discussion here: https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger/issues/87

**EDIT:** So I recently was able to reproduce this kind of error! It may not be the same cause as what you experienced, but who knows, anything is possible :-).

So my issue was actually caused by the nvidia drivers in linux! Apparently it was playing games with the signal processing masks that processes got, which was causing me to get this same error. Updating drivers fixed it at least for me. Hopefully, this will help anyone who stumbles across this question and happened to have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I saw this error when trying to open a binary that was owned by root with **644** privileges. **chmod** to **755** and chown to regular user took care of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue where **edb** couldn't run **crossfire**. My issue was because I was running `64bit` live cd and **crossfire** couldn't run so **edb** threw error.

**Installed 32bit support lib(libc6-i386) and edb runs fine.**

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the binary was not set to executable. Use Chmod to set it as executable. And run evan debugger as root. 
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but anyway, I reconstruct what I did and explain the solution.

I started a text editor (Kate), build assembly programs and save them onto the harddisk, the directory where in I wanted to save I've created within the 'save as' dialog box.
I assembled the program and started it with edb --run ./myprogram.
And indeed "Failed to open and attach to process, please check privileges and try again." dialogbox.

The solution to my problem. I've changed the permissions on the folder (only) to 777 and it worked.
A strange thing is when I reconstructed the error, it was dissappeared. (First folder was ipv42hex, second folder was test. Both folders had dwrx-rx--x permission.